# Latency issue with Elastic Load balancer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am using aws elastic load balancer in production mode.I am experiencing latency issues with ELB. The  cloud watch monitor show 3sec to 10 sec response time. When resulted the increases load time of the web site. Customers are complaining regarding the speed issues. I am not to figure out the reason for the problem,also stickiness is disabled and application based cookies are also disabled. Kindly help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you having large spikes of traffic? If so, please know that the ELB scales pretty slow (50% every 5 minutes). You can refer to this article for more info: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1636185810492479.

If you have a relatively constant traffic usage, you have probably saturated the EC2 instance that you are currently using. In this case you should implement an auto-scaling policy, so that you have enough compute power for your current usage.

Basically, unless you have more traffic that the ELB can temporarily handle (this issue solves itself automatically as the ELB scales), this should not be an ELB issue. I've seen latencies as low as 100ms through elb, at over 100k RPM.

Comment: I dont have a large traffic spikes and the traffic is constant. My EC2 instances are not saturated. It has not crossed 60% of cpu in both the availability zones. I raised a ticket, aws guys up graded my ELB now its fine. The issue was with the out dated ELB version.